# Chrome web driver: Can't sign in

Tags: python, selenium, automation

This may be a duplicate of another post but I'm gonna ask it anyway. So I was trying to create a simple youtube login automation using selenium in python and the chrome webdriver. Whenever I try to sign in a get an error saying that this app may not be secure or something. Yes, I have less secure apps enabled on my account and yes, I have two factor authentication disabled. Here is the code in case you were wondering:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from pynput.keyboard import Key, Controller
from keyboard import press
import time

keyboard = Controller()

browser = webdriver.Chrome()

browser.get("https://youtube.com/watch?v=1JvmK7XH1Ao")

time.sleep(3)

browser.find_element_by_link_text("SIGN IN").click()

time.sleep(3)

keyboard.type(#myUsername)

time.sleep(1)

press('enter')
```

Image added
  https://i.stack.imgur.com/w1I4i.png

Comment: Could you please send the screenshot of error to us so that it will be easy for us to find the root cause.

Comment: @UnknownBeast Please read why a [screenshot of HTML or code or error is a bad idea](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors). Consider suggesting OP to update the Question with formatted text based relevant HTML, code trials and error stack trace.

Comment: google doesn't like bots to login.